# I am finding this error in php "Cannot access offset of type string on string in"

Tags: php

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in" this type of error showing me
"Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\xampp\htdocs...php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs...php on line 10"

How to Solve this type of error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, as well as any debugging observations you have made.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you're trying to treat a string as an array or object, but it doesn't have the expected structure.

Since you havent provided the code so here are some of the things you can check and debug in order to resolve this issue:

Make sure you're not using square brackets ([]) to access characters in a string unless it's structured like an array. Ensure that variables you're working with are of the correct type. If you're expecting an array or object but receiving a string, it could cause this error. If the error occurs within a function call, double-check the arguments being passed to the function to ensure they match the expected types.

Additionally, consider using var_dump() or print_r() to inspect variable values at the problematic line. This can provide insights into the data you're working with and help identify any unexpected values or types.

Hope these steps assist you in resolving your error.

Comment: Did you use AI to create this generic answer? Rember that's [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) here